# Date Format Convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am dealing with sql DB where the date is recorded in this format '2020-348T08:55'. I need to convert this to datetime.

Please guide if there is possible way to do that?

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format, are you saying you're storing is as a different data type? If so, you need to fix your design. What date does your value represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With string and date/time functions extract the year and days to create a DATETIME without the time and finally add the time part:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(DATEADD(
    DAY, 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX('T', col) - 1), 6, LEN(col)) AS INTEGER), 
    DATEFROMPARTS(CAST(LEFT(col, 4) AS INTEGER) - 1, 12, 31)
  ) AS DATETIME) + 
  CAST(RIGHT(col, 5) AS DATETIME) AS result
FROM tablename
```

If the *days* part is always a 3 digit number, it can be simplified:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(DATEADD(
    DAY, 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 6, 3) AS INTEGER), 
    DATEFROMPARTS(CAST(LEFT(col, 4) AS INTEGER) - 1, 12, 31)
  ) AS DATETIME) + 
  CAST(RIGHT(col, 5) AS DATETIME) AS result
FROM tablename
```

Replace `col` with your column's name.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8eb25016a0762b7f5245f968a6356bab).
Result:

```
> | result                  |
> | :---------------------- |
> | 2020-12-13 08:55:00.000 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and now how can I do reverse ex: 2020-12-13 08:55 to  '2020-348T08:55'. When doing query i want to set date in date time format and have declare to 2020-348T08:55:29.752-05:00

Comment: @Student this is a new requirement for which you must ask a new question.